# range.select() gives error

Tags: c#, office-interop, worksheet

I am a novice user of C# and I am trying to store the values of a column from an excel file with a specific header. To find the header I am looking all the columns and rows and search for the name. Buut I am getting an error on the line with `FindRange.Select();` command. During the debugging when it hit the line it goes back to the line
 `FindRange = xlWorksheet[0].UsedRange.Columns[columnIndex];`

(Ps. I have taken the code from another online source)

Here is the code;

```
int columnCount = xlWorksheet[0].UsedRange.Columns.Count;
                    List<int>[] columnValue = new List<int>[columnCount];
                Excel.Range rngResult = null;
                Excel.Range rng = null;
                int index = 0;

            int rowCount = xlWorksheet[0].UsedRange.Rows.Count;
            Excel.Range FindRange = null;

            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= xlWorksheet[0].UsedRange.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
            {
                FindRange = xlWorksheet[0].UsedRange.Columns[columnIndex];

                try
                {
                    FindRange.Select();
                    rngResult = FindRange.Find(What: "Satış", LookIn: Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, SearchOrder: Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows);

                    if (rngResult != null)
                    {
                        columnValue[index] = new List<int>();

                        for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= xlWorksheet[0].UsedRange.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
                        {
                            rng = xlWorksheet[0].UsedRange[rowIndex, columnIndex] as Excel.Range;
                            if (rng.Value != null)
                            {
                                columnValue[index].Add(rng.Value.ToString());

                            }

                            index++;
                        }
                        Array.Resize(ref columnValue, index);
                    }

                }

                catch (Exception E)
                {
                    if (E.InnerException != null)
                    {
                        string err = E.InnerException.Message;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: What is the reason for calling `FindRange.Select()`? If you want to activate that range in Excel use `FindRange.Activate()` which will highlight the current range.